# jQuery UI Draggable set drag length without containment property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div without any parent element and I want the draggable DIV to drag to top and bottom but not all the way. I have done the top using,

```
drag: function (event, ui) {
      if(ui.position.top < 50)
      ui.position.top = 50;
},
```

However, I can't figure out a way to do this to bottom. When the element is dragged to the bottom I need to prevent it dragging from a certain position.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Letn0uy9/)

HTML

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
<p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        axis: 'y',
    containment: 'window',
        scroll: false,
    cancel: false,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
          if(ui.position.top < 50)
          ui.position.top = 50;
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the parent/container's height to calculate the bottom offset:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'window',
  scroll: false,
  cancel: false,
  drag: function (event, ui) {
    var offset = 50;
    var maxHeight = (window.innerHeight - this.offsetHeight - offset);

    if (ui.position.top < offset) {
      ui.position.top = offset;
      return false;
    } 
    else if (ui.position.top > maxHeight) {
      ui.position.top = maxHeight;
      return false;
    }
  }    
});
```

Returning `false` might be required for canceling or basically "releasing" the dragging effect when it goes outside of the boundaries.

---

Here's your fiddle with the above changes:

```js
$("#draggable").draggable({
  axis: 'y',
  containment: 'window',
  scroll: false,
  cancel: false,
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var offset = 50;
    var maxHeight = (window.innerHeight - this.offsetHeight - offset);

    if (ui.position.top < offset) {
      ui.position.top = offset;
      //return false;
    } 
    else if (ui.position.top > maxHeight) {
      ui.position.top = maxHeight;
      //turn false;
    }
  },

});
```

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ui-widget-content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to determine the parent/container of this draggable element yourself, in your example fiddle, it is the `window`, so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, if you try to drag the element in the same direction over and over the offset has been incremented.

Comment: Dragging over and over? I tested the above in your fiddle and it seemed to work.

Comment: Try the following scenario, 

Drag up the element all the way to the top and drag down the element again and all the way to the top again keep doing that for a few times. You will notice the draggable element won't go all the way to the top.

Comment: Removing the return fixed it. Thanks for the help. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Yep, I noticed that too. Perhaps you need to set the initial top position for this draggable element to be the offset, only then will the `return false` thing work properly. Please try the above snippet in full-page mode.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your div has no parent and you want to drag this across the entire document, you should add this to your code

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
        axis: 'y',
    containment: 'window',
        scroll: false,
    cancel: false,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
          if(ui.position.top < 50)
          ui.position.top = 50;
          if(ui.position.top > $(document).height() - 50)
          ui.position.top = $(document).height() - 50;
    },

});
```